# File updated deployed, new file ignored

Tags: azure-devops

I create a web project with Visual Studio. 
I use GitHub desktop app to push my code to my Github
I create an Azure DevOps project throught the Azure portal to create a CI and don't change anything

When I commit a change all the CI run, the build is done with success and a new deployment is done.

To be sure everything work I did 2 differents tests

First : I created a new HTML file in my project with the other HTML files. When I commit, build and deployment run on Azure Devops without error, but I cannot see my new file in the wwwroot folder

Second : I updated a existing HTML file. When I commit, build and deployment run on Azure Devops without error, and I can see my update on the file present on the web app.

Why this difference ? I would like understood why update work correctly but not the add. I don't know where start to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Can you see the new file in the git hub?
Did you add the new html file to Visual Studio project?

Comment: Yes I can see the file on my github repository, and I add the file to my visual studio project without any fancy. right click => new item => HTML file. I can reach this new file when I run the project from visual studio

Comment: To try to find, I get the zip create by the build part. And of course my file is not present, so at least I know that the issue come from the build process. I add the clean parameter but without any change. If someone had a idea...

Comment: do you use yaml pipeline? could you share the code of the pipeline here?

Comment: Can you also try to create additional repository on the azure devops git and try to push your code there? (just for test purpose)

Comment: I try it, I create a new AzureDevops project and import inside the github project, same issue with the file not added. I think the issue come from the VSBuild task, but I don't know how change that

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the "build action" of the new .cshtml file?

In visual studio, right click on the file and go to properties.
Check if the build action is set to "Content", if not set it to content and commit.

Other build actions sometimes will not show any error but the view file will not be copied upon build. This is not Azure DevOps issue, rather visual studio filetype issue.

Let me know if this was the case. Good luck :)